# Puppeteer's `page.evaluate` result differs from devTools console

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I need to check for a certain service worker being registered. Unfortunately, `page.evaluate` returns `undefined` no matter what I do.

```js
let page = await chrome.newPage();
await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:8089/');
await page.waitFor(10000);

const isCorrectSW = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await navigator
        .serviceWorker
        .getRegistrations()
        .then(registrations =>
            registrations[0].active.scriptURL.endsWith('/target.js')
        );
});
console.log(isCorrectSW);
```

`isCorrectSW` ends up being `undefined`, but if I enable devtools and run the same statement in the Chromium instance's devtools, I get the correct result. I can also observe the service worker attached in the browser's dev tools.

Is this a Puppeteer bug, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) returns undefined when the function passed returns a non-serializable value.

In your scenario, the function you are passing into page.evaulate does not return anything.

You are already using async, you can switch the function you are passing to be:

```
async () => {
    const registrations = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
    return registrations[0].active.scriptURL.endsWith('/target.js')
}
```

Comment: ~~That seems to work, though I fail to understand why. Functionally they're the same thing? A boolean is returned either way, which is serializable of course.~~ Oh, duh, I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the issue is that you need to add a `return` statement, as the function itself does not return anything, but the statement inside the function does have a resulting value after the promise settles. You could also switch it from `async () =>{}` to `async () => ()`.

Comment: Yup, exactly that, forgot the `return`.